# Help with induction proof for recurrent function

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction, factorial

I am having issues with the following inductive proof.

> Prove by induction on $n$ that $$ a(n) = n!\bigg(\frac{1}{0!} + \frac{1}{1!} + \cdots + \frac{1}{(n-1)!}\bigg)$$ for all $n \geq 1,$ where
>   $$
> a(n)=
> \begin{cases}
> n\big(a(n-1)+1\big) & \text{if } n \geq 1; \\[0.1in]
> 0 & \text{if } n=0.
> \end{cases}
> $$

**Attempt at Solving**

1. Firstly, let's prove the base case $n=0$: this is trivial since $a(0)=0.$
2. Now, an inductive assumption. Assume result holds when $n=N-1$. Let's prove that it holds when $n= N$:
   \begin{align}
   a(N) & = N\big(a(N-1)+1\big) \\[0.1in]
   & = N (N-1)! \bigg(\frac{1}{0!} + \cdots + \frac{1}{(n-2)!} \bigg) \\[0.1in]
   & = N! \bigg(\frac{1}{0!} + \cdots + \frac{1}{(n-2)!} \bigg).
   \end{align}

Hmm - I'm stuck; now what? - Is what I have done so far, correct?

Any tips or pointers would be great. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think the base case you want is $n=1$. I'm also confused about what you are trying to show. It seems like you can just let $a(n)$ be equal to whatever you want.

Comment: Huh - but on the original equation the base case is n=0.. Hmm

Comment: I'm just thinking that because $a(n)=0$ only for $n=0$. So if you induct on $n$ but $a(n) \neq 0$ after the base case, what is the point of induction? (not a rhetorical question)

Comment: Sorry - I am a bit new to this. To me, it seems that a(0)=0 is the base case, because it will always eventually land on a(0)

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "eventually land on $a(0)$.

Comment: You simply dropped a term: $\displaystyle N \bigg((N-1)! \bigg(\frac{1}{0!} + \cdots + \frac{1}{(n-2)!} \bigg)+1\bigg)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It holds for $n=1$.

Assume that it holds for $n=k$, i.e.
$$a(k)=k!\left(\frac{1}{0!}+\frac{1}{1!}+\cdots+\frac{1}{(k-1)!}\right).$$
Then, we have

$$\begin{align}a(k+1)&=(k+1)(a(k)+1)\\&=(k+1)\left(k!\left(\frac{1}{0!}+\frac{1}{1!}+\cdots+\frac{1}{(k-1)!}\right)+1\right)\\&=(k+1)!\left(\frac{1}{0!}+\frac{1}{1!}+\cdots+\frac{1}{(k-1)!}\right)+k+1\\&=(k+1)!\left(\frac{1}{0!}+\frac{1}{1!}+\cdots+\frac{1}{(k-1)!}\right)+(k+1)!\cdot\frac{1}{k!}\\&=(k+1)!\left(\frac{1}{0!}+\frac{1}{1!}+\cdots+\frac{1}{(k-1)!}+\frac{1}{k!}\right)\end{align}$$

Hence, it holds for $n=k+1$.

Comment: Cool thanks a lot @mathlove. But how did you know that n=1 was the base case instead of n=0? I am confused on that part.

Comment: @user1008537: The question says that 'Prove ... for all $n\ge 1$'.

Answer (score 0):

You simply dropped a term:

$$ N \bigg((N-1)! \bigg(\frac{1}{0!} + \cdots + \frac{1}{(n-2)!} \bigg)\  \underbrace{{}+1}\bigg)$$